# Require Username entry on Login | Ingresar usuario y clave al iniciar la sesion

Tags: greeter

I have elementary OS 6 (Odin) installed and I need to have the Greeter require a username to be typed in rather than selected from a list. Existing users should be completely hidden from anyone accessing the system.

How can I do this?

---

*Original Question (Spanish)*

Tengo instalado elementary os 6 odin y requiero que al presentarse la pantalla de login me permita ingresar el usuario y luego la clave. Actualmente me presenta los usuarios que tengo creados y debo seleccionar uno de ellos

Answer (score 1):

There is a `greeter-hide-users` switch available for use in the configuration and can be used together with `greeter-show-manual-login`.

What works for me is a `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-custom.conf` file with the following content:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-show-manual-login=true
allow-guest=false
greeter-hide-users=true
```